# Vertically center a block in CSS

Tags: html, css, alignment

I'm trying to achieve following result:

[image]

How can I vertically align 2nd block to the middle of page. (In mobile devices too)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flexbox to the rescue. Given a simple html layout like this:

```
<header></header>
<main>
    <h1>Heading</h1>
    <h2>Sub Heading</h2>
    <div>
        <a href="#">Click Me</a>
        <a href="#">Click Me</a>
    </div>
</main>
<footer></footer>
```

You can center the contents in `<main>` with a few lines of code:

```
main {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-flow: column;
}
```

The first rule establishes the flexbox context, the middle style rules align the content vertically and horizontally, and the last rule makes sure the items are aligned top to bottom, not left to right. Since the anchor buttons are contained within a div, the div itself is what's being aligned by flexbox, and the buttons are free to sit side by side.

https://jsfiddle.net/858vr2hf/

**EDIT:**

Updated fiddle with background image:

https://jsfiddle.net/s3dytc31/

Comment: Thanks! I guess it will work, but need to modify my existing layout.

All the three blocks are wrapped in a parent container which has background image.

So, the main, footer and header are part of a parent which has background image. (It is not working as it has parent).

Second thing, I'm concern about FlexBox support. I'm targeting Firefox and Chrome with mostly latest version.

Comment: With the little modification in your code and use of `calc` function, I achieved my desire result.
Thanks!

Comment: No problem. Also, see my edit for a pure flexbox solution. Flexbox is fully supported by Firefox and Chrome, FYI.

Comment: Yep, I have checked on caniuse.com, I hope CSS4 will solve many problems in future.

Answer (score 1):

Give position:relative to that light blue (wrapper div).

and add following css for the div you want to center:

```
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
width: 100%;
-moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
text-align: center;
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: It won't work as All the tree boxes are wrapped by one parent. So, the Middle block is occupying exact height based on contents in it.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T5RIh4StIvs&list=PLfdtiltiRHWGWDxSpG63YcFuv1WuEUWIm&index=1) tutorial. It teaches in an easy manner how to vertically center elements.